# Ajax send request but php don't get any $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

jquery version: 3.6.0
php version: 8.1.4

Trying to pass POSt but php gets empty $_POST

index.html

```
    <button onclick="func()">Click me</button>
    <script>
function func()
{
    var eventID = "test";
  $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {'variable': eventID },

        success: function (response) {

          console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
    </script>
```

test.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['variable'])) 
 {
   echo($_POST['variable']);
 }
 else
 {
   echo ("failure");
 }
?>
```

edit:
PHP ReQuest

```
https://pastebin.com/ASjjxAm1
```

var_dump

```
failurearray(0) {
}
```

I tried every configuration. I think I'm losing my mind

Comment: seems to work OK with jQuery 3.3.1 which is the highest version available here in the snippet editor

Comment: Still don't work same erro empty $_POST

Comment: So, what exactly do you see in the Console afterwards? It works fine for me

Comment: "failure" it's like $_POST is never recieved

Comment: Are you sure that's as the result of the correct ajax request? I can't reproduce it. Also, in that case, have you looked up the ajax request in your browser's Network tool and double checked that it's definitely being sent as POST and that the "variable" parameter is definitely included in the outgoing request data? Also please do `var_dump($_POST);` on the php side so we can see what, if anything, is in there.